# Temporarily adjust message alert and call volume

Tags: settings, volume-control

I can't be the only person with the problem that you temporarily turn down the volume of your calls and texts (in a quiet place), and then three days later it's still quiet and you miss alerts.

Is there any way to adjust the volume only temporarily? Or, to put it a different way, is there a way to automatically reset the ringer volume to a predefined level each day?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several ways to get your volume levels back. Personally I like to use the [IFTTT](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.ifttt.ifttt) app to set my ringer volume to maximum when I connect to my home WiFi. ([recipe](https://ifttt.com/recipes/191202-if-connect-to-home-network-set-ringer-to-maximum))

If you want to fix your volume at a specific time, say, you can create a new recipe using the [Date & Time Channel](https://ifttt.com/date_and_time).

Comment: Perfect, I never would have thought of that.

Comment: IFTTT is awesome.

Answer (score 1):

An option for you might be the [Silent Mode Widget](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.guywmustang.silentwidget).

It puts a widget on your homescreen to silence / restore your volume settings with a single tap.

(I have not tried this app. There also appear to be several other similar apps that you might try instead.)